# How to return random dates in a month

Tags: excel, date, text

Have a fun little exercise that has gotten very not fun:

In a cell, I want to randomly return of eleven dates. 
In the second cell, I want to randomly return one of ten dates (the other seven and NOT the returned date in the first cell). 
In the third cell, I want to return one of nine dates (I do not want the dates above!)

The dates are the M/Fs of July / some of August.

Specifically:
7/11
7/18
7/25
7/13
8/1
8/8

7/14
7/21
7/28
8/4
8/11

Is this possible with Excel? Thanks! I assume I could use some sort of vlookup in a table in tandem with rand function.

Jason

Comment: [This?](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/generate-random-dates-within-a-specific-date-range/)

Comment: almost, but how does this work with non-contiguous dates?

Comment: [Test if it is a weekday](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/weekday-function-HP010343015.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want non-contiguous dates, try listing them out and picking with INDEX:

=INDEX({"7/11","7/18","7/25","7/13","8/1","8/8","7/14","7/21","7/28","8/4","8/11"},RANDBETWEEN(1,11))

If these dates aren't going to change, there shouldn't be a problem referring to them in the function like that. If they change, you might want to put them in a reference table, or move them to a named variable to make it easier to edit.

Comment: randbetween will use replacement, I don't think they want duplicates.

Comment: This is super close, but as xQbert pointed out, does not get around the duplicate issue.